# Using a pointer to a Mutex (pthread_mutex_t *) in a structure, Instead of a global Mutex

Tags: c, pthreads, mutex

I'm using a lock (pthread_mutex_t) in a program that launches a number of threads, all threads receives a pointer to a structure, which contains a pointer to this mutex.

So there is one initialized mutex, and all structures have a pointer to it but it doesn't works well, I don't understand why?

Here is some example code, I tried to make it as minimal as possible.

Lets call my program `duck`:

`duck.c`

```
# include "duck.h"

void    *exec_threads(void *arg)
{
    struct s_duck   *duck;

    duck = (struct s_duck*)arg;
    pthread_mutex_lock(duck->mutex);
    printf("duck nbr %i\n", duck->n);
    pthread_mutex_unlock(duck->mutex);
    return (NULL);
}

int main(void)
{
    pthread_t       *id;
    pthread_mutex_t *mutex;
    struct s_duck   *duck;
    int             n;
    int             i;

    n = 5; // number of threads
    id = malloc(sizeof(int) * n); // allocate id[n]
    mutex = malloc(sizeof(pthread_mutex_t)); // allocate mutex
    pthread_mutex_init(mutex, NULL); // init mutex
    duck = init_chain_ducks(mutex, n); // create chained list of structure
    i = 0;
    while (i < n)
    {
        pthread_create(&id[i], NULL, &exec_threads, duck); // launch threads
        duck = duck->next;
        i++;
    }
    i = 0;
    while (i < n)
    {
        pthread_join(id[i], NULL); // join threads
        i++;
    }
    write(1, "the end\n", 8);
    return (0);
}
```

`duck_chain.c`

```
# include "duck.h"

struct s_duck   *init_chain_ducks(pthread_mutex_t *mutex, int n)
{   
    struct s_duck   *new;
    struct s_duck   *duck;
    int         i;

    i = n;
    duck = NULL;
    while (i > 0)
    {
        new = malloc(sizeof(struct s_duck));
        new->n = i;
        new->mutex = mutex; // this is where the pointer to the mutex is stored
        new->next = duck;
        duck = new;
        i--;
    }
    return (duck);
}
```

`duck.h`

```
#ifndef DUCK_H
# define DUCK_H

# include <stdio.h>
# include <stdlib.h>
# include <string.h>
# include <unistd.h>
# include <pthread.h>

struct s_duck
{
    int             n;
    pthread_mutex_t *mutex;
    struct s_duck   *next;
};

struct s_duck   *init_chain_ducks(pthread_mutex_t *mutex, int n);

#endif
```

If i use a global variable for the mutex instead, it works well. But with the pointer in the structure, i get something like an undefined behaviour:

Most of the time i get this output :

```
duck nbr 1
duck nbr 3
duck nbr 4
duck nbr 5
duck nbr 2
[2]    18914 segmentation fault (core dumped)  ./a.out
```

The segfault happens during the `pthread_join()` but i also get those two errors often:

```
duck nbr 1
duck nbr 2
[wait indefinitely]
```

Or:

```
duck nbr 1
duck nbr 4
duck nbr 3
a.out: ../nptl/pthread_mutex_lock.c:81: __pthread_mutex_lock: Assertion `mutex->__data.__owner == 0' failed.
[2]    20394 abort (core dumped)  ./a.out
```

I must be doing some basic mistake, but I don't know where.

(compilation : `gcc duck.c duck_chain.c -lpthread`)

Comment: Note that although it is permissible for your structure to contain a `pthread_mutex_t *` by which your threads access a mutex, that seems a bit excessive in levels of indirection.  A possible alternative would be to give your structure a member of type `pthread_mutex_t`, instead of a pointer to one.  That makes especial sense when the mutex's purpose is to protect the other members of the structure, but it is not limited to that case.

Comment: ok, but here each thread receive a different structure (it's a chained list, with at much element than there are threads), so if they contain a `pthread_mutex_t` that wouldn't work ? or do i miss something ?

Comment: You are correct.  If each thread receives a different structure but they need to access the same mutex then that mutex cannot itself be a member of the structure, whereas a pointer to it can.  I guess with your code I would have stuck with a global mutex, or else created a higher-level structure to represent the whole linked list, and put the mutex there.

Comment: `a higher-level structure to represent the whole linked list`, ho yes, i might do that indeed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
pthread_t       *id;

id = malloc(sizeof(int) * n); // allocate id[n]
```

`id` is not an `int` - it's `pthread_t`. Should be `sizeof(pthread_t)`. Use a little trick and use the pointer points to.

```
id = malloc(sizeof(*id) * n);
```

Compile with `-g -Wall -Wextra -fsanitize=undefined,address` - sanitizer will help you catch such mistakes.

Comment: thanks, that was it ! and thx for the tips (i actually use -Wall -Wextra and -Werror, i didn't mention it, but i don't use -fsanitize most of the time, i will now). I'm confuse though, why no problem happened when i used a global mutex insted of this version, since the problem wasn't the mutex after all ?

Comment: Variables were in different places, and it just so happened that at `((int*)id)[n]` there was nothing there, so it was going undetected.

Comment: So it was by chance ? I don't think so, i mean, i tested it a lot of time, it was not just a one time hazard. It systematically works with my error but a global declaration of the mutex variable, and it systematically fail without the global declaration, because of my error. But my error has nothing to do with the global variable, so i don't understand this (I don't need to, just curious)

Comment: `So it was by chance ?` You have written invalid code, everything that happens is "by chance", it works by chance and fails by chance. `has nothing to do with the global variable` Your code writes out-of-bounds to the allocated memory, whatever is "after" that memory is overwritten. You have not shown your other code - i suspect, that nothing relevant was placed by the compiler in the region that was overwritten, the error came undetected.

Comment: yes, but your explanation is that `it just so happened that at ((int*)id)[n] there was nothing`, so if i try it over and over again i should get an error, not more nor less often when i declare mutex as a global variable than not, right ? Actually, i'll edit my question to add the version with the global variable, i think i miss something in you explanation

Comment: No - "just so happened" is not a guarantee. In your code there are threads, they are unsequenced, so any of them can execute first or at the same time with the others, resulting in different outputs. Really, there is no point in reasoning about invalid code (about "_undefined behavior_") - the only thing you can do is inspect the actual assembly code and see what happens.

Comment: well, while testing for the update of the question, i understood what you where saying, i don't need to make the edition anymore, thanks for the answers !